# Pool de conexões de servidor para aplicação web

Tags: java, mongodb, conexão, pooling

gostaria de saber se é possível implementar um pool de conexões em um servidor e fazer com que ele distribua as conexões para aplicações desktop java, caso seja possível gostaria de um direcionamento do que pesquisar para implementar isso utilizando Java e o banco MongoDB.

**Cenário**

Preciso fazer com que as estações que tenham a minha aplicação desktop façam uso de um banco de dados, porém por se tratar de uma aplicação que pode estar inserindo cerca de mais de 200 mil linhas de informações por usuário a distribuição de conexões deve ser cautelosa para evitar gargalos, pensei em optar por uma arquitetura de um banco embarcado e outro externo(para diminuir a carga do mesmo), porém não encontrei um banco embarcado confiável com o Java, e por isso optei por apenas um mais com acesso controlado.

Desde já agradeço qualquer resposta.

Comment: Você já ouviu falar do HikariPool ou c3p0? São gerenciadores de pool de conexões com o banco de dados, se entendi a sua pergunta isso pode te ajudar.
Hikari: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP.
c3p0: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/.

Comment: @luanlucas já ouvi sim, mas geralmente eles são utilizados dentro das aplicações web para prover conexões para os clientes que acessam a aplicação no servidor não é? a minha dúvida é como eu teria esses caras rodando lá só pra me liberar uma conexão para as estações, obrigado por responder se não for esta a definição correta por favor me corrija, mais uma vez, grato.

Comment: sinceramente eu não conheço bem a ponto de discordar, até onde sei é isso mesmo que você comentou. Voltando a sua pergunta... infelizmente não poderei ajudar :/ boa sorte.